# Add array as dynamic value in Paw App

Tags: paw-app

I have a group of two requests in Paw. The first one returns a JSON array in the response. The second one is a POST request which posts a JSON Object and should include the (root) array from the first response for one of the keys.

As I see it, I can only add dynamic values for strings, am I missing something here? If I set the parameter to String and add the response as dynamic value (and using the awesome jq extension for extracting the important bits) the string is automatically escaped and no longer a JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround by using the Text data type, then setting the header of the request to be Json. See attachments.

Create the JSON data manually - this will allow you to supply a dynamic array.

[image: Set data type to Text]

Manually specify the header data type to be JSON. It will default to text.

[image: Set Header Value]

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this post is old, but for whoever runs across it and needs help, there's an option to select different types by clicking on the icon.

[image: Paw -- pass in an array]

Comment: After choosing Array, how the array items should be written? if I try [1,2,3] or anything else it shows me the following warning: "data should be array"